# Why does the company or organisation say 1 person and not the number of employees at the company?

Tags: support, developer-story

When I enter the company or organisation name in my developer story and a URL it shows only one person works for that organisation and doesn't link to the actual company or count of employees that have also worked for them.

This is misleading. It makes it look like I've only worked for companies I've made up, not the impression I want to give to people viewing my developer story.

Obviously nothing prevents me from putting down a fictitious position as a "Super Awesome Developer" for Stack Overflow, but then anyone checking my job history or getting references would quickly discover it wasn't real and that I haven't worked for Stack Overflow which would discourage people from being dishonest.

Comment: Just to make reference at your example:  you're probably right, but any employer who doesn't verify where you've worked is probably not a company you'd want to work for anyway.

Comment: Isn't it like that, that the company should invite you to be part of the company page, or is this only for the jobs segment?

Comment: This is only for the developer story, I'm not talking about the company page (obviously a company will cherry-pick its employees to display on their page).